# Email verification with one click link

Tags: javascript, node.js

I did this code which helping me to verify my email for registration. Firstly I am setting a secret token in my database against every user while registration.Then I am sending that secret token to individual email with a message and paste this token to users verify page for verification.

That's my registration API :

```js
router.post('/register', (req, res) => {

    const secretToken = randomstring.generate();
    var name = req.body.name;
    var username = req.body.username;
    var email = req.body.email;
    var password = req.body.password;
    var cpassword = req.body.cpassword;

   

   req.checkBody('name','Name is required').notEmpty();
   req.checkBody('email','Email is required').notEmpty();
   req.checkBody('email', 'Email is not valid').isEmail();
   req.checkBody('username','username is required').notEmpty();
   req.checkBody('password','password is required').notEmpty();
   req.checkBody('cpassword','passwords do not match').equals(req.body.password);
   var errors = req.validationErrors();
   if(errors)
   {
       res.render('register', {
           errors: errors
       });
   }
   else
   {
    User.findOne({email: req.body.email}, function(err, existingUser)
    {
            if(existingUser)
            {
                req.flash('error_msg', 'Email address already exits try different one!!');
                res.redirect('/users/register');
                console.log("In db save body");
            }
            else
            {
            var newUser = new User(
                {
                    name:name,
                    email:email, 
                    username:username,
                    password:password,
                    secretToken:secretToken,
                    active: false
                });
      
            User.createUser(newUser, (err,user) => {
                  if(err) throw err;
                  console.log(user);
            });
            
            //Composing email
            const html = `Hi there
            <br/>
            Thank you for registering!
            <br/><br/>
            Please verify your email by typing following token:
            <br/>
            Token : <b>${secretToken}<b>
            <br/>
            On the following page : 
            <a href="https://login-app-passport.herokuapp.com/users/verify">https://login-app-passport.herokuapp.com/users/verify</a>
            <br/><br/>
            Have a good day!`;

            mailer.sendEmail('admin@teamfly.com',email,'Please verify your email',html);
            req.flash('success_msg','Please check your email');
            res.redirect('/users/login');
          }


    });
    }
    

});
```

When I am putting my secret token my database updated as secretToken to null and active state false to true.

That's my verify API:

```js
router.route('/verify')
.get( (req, res) => {
    res.render('verify');
})
.post( (req, res, next) => {
    
        const {secretToken} = req.body;
        const user = User.findOne({'secretToken' : secretToken.trim()}).then((user) => {
            if(!user)
            {
                req.flash('error_msg', 'No user found');
                res.redirect('/users/verify');
                return;
            }
        
            user.active = true;
            user.secretToken = '';
            user.save();
         
            
           
        
            req.flash('success_msg','Thank you.You can now login');
            res.redirect('/users/login');
        });
            

    
        

        

    
    
});
```

My question is I want to send a link that will contain the secret token and when I am clicking that link I want my database to update automatically(secretToken to null and active state to true)and redirect me to login route. I don't want to copy the secret token from email and paste it to verify page.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Place the `secretToken` on the verify url. Users click on that url (or copy/paste the url into browser), extract the token from the url and update your database.

Make sure `secretToken` contains only url-safe characters, otherwise you'll need to url-encode it.

Email message:

```
<a href="https://login-app-passport.herokuapp.com/users/verify/${secretToken}">https://login-app-passport.herokuapp.com/users/verify/${secretToken}</a>
```

I don't know which router you're using, but you'll only need a GET /verify/:token, no need for a POST route. Extract the token from `.params` (or query string if you prefer, update the url accordingly).

```
router.route('/verify/:secretToken')
.get( (req, res) => {
    const {secretToken} = req.params;
    const user = User.findOne({'secretToken' : secretToken.trim()}).then((user) => {
        if(!user)
        {
            req.flash('error_msg', 'No user found');
            res.redirect('/users/verify-error');
            return;
        }

        user.active = true;
        user.secretToken = '';
        user.save();

        req.flash('success_msg','Thank you.You can now login');
        res.redirect('/users/login');
    });
```

Comment: showing this error TypeError: Cannot match against 'undefined' or 'null'.
    at router.route.get (F:\nodeJS_Practice\node_project_passport\routes\users.js:184:35)

Comment: Error in this line const {secretToken} = req.body.params;

Comment: It should be `const {secretToken} = req.params;`

Answer (score 0):

Simply use a url param you fill with your token and update once you find the user:

Your verification part:

```
router.route("/verify/:token").get((res, req) => {
    const token = req.params.token;
    User.findOneAndUpdate({secretToken: token}, {$set: {secretToken:null, active:true}}, (err, user) => {
        if (!err) res.redirect("/users/login")
    });
});
```

Your registration part:

```
const verificationLink = `https://login-app-passport.herokuapp.com/verify/${token}`;
const html = `Hi there
<br>
Thank you for registering!
<br><br>
Please verify your email by following this link:
<br>
<b>${verificationLink}<b>
<br>
Have a good day!`;
```